# DevExpress under Delphi XE doesn't work

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe

I've installed the trial version of DevExpress. I can drag and drop DevExpress components on my form, but if I try to compile, Delphi XE says that it could't find the files from DevExpress which are written in the `uses` section.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you have enabled runtime packages for your project and that the devExpress packages are listed. Do this in the project options dialog.

[image]

If you had the full version of devExpress then you could optionally link the source files directly into your application without using runtime packages. However, that is not possible for the trial version.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the solution for my problem :)

Comment: I haven't forgotten it, but when you have answered my question and I wanted to accept your answer, there was shown a message which said that I needed to wait 3 minutes before I can accept your answer. So I went upstairs for lunch and now I will accept it ;)

Comment: @Henry Understood and thanks. Plenty of newcomers aren't as well-versed in the ways of SO as you.

Comment: @michael85 Thanks for the screenshot work, but how did you do it without leaving traces of my previous scruffy work?